# Separating SQL Server update string

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, sql-update, separator

I am trying to figure out if there is a way of separating the needed data in a string like so:

```
 number = 3,
 line = 1,
 hardwarePartNum = '',
 ...
 inv_status = 3,
 inv_netName = 1,
 inv_maintGrp = 3,
 inv_maintVen = 4,
 ...
 qty_SerialNum = '',
 qty_Location = '',
 qty_Property = '',
 ...
```

As you see above, I have 3 different types of values that I need to update the values to in my query.

The `inv_...` and the `qty_...` are one table and the first set of 3 values (those values that have no `zzz_` in front of them) are in another table.

How, and is it possible, to separate these values in 2 groups. First group being without the `zzz_` and the second ground being `inv_...` and `qty_...`.

Once I have them separated then I can do something like this:

```
UPDATE 
    bLine 
SET 
    @val1 
WHERE 
    theGuid = @val2;

UPDATE 
    invLine2 
SET 
    @val3 
WHERE 
    theGuid = @val4;
```

So giving the above:

```
@val1 = number = 3,line = 1,hardwarePartNum = '',....
@val2 = 54grs-r459-32r-6exlq-15g4
@val3 = inv_status = 3,inv_netName = 1,inv_maintGrp = 3,inv_maintVen = 4,qty_SerialNum = '',qty_Location = '',qty_Property = '',....
@val4 = a45vz-u300-2bd-4710j-vf09
```

I'm sure some type of **regex** could do something like that but I'm not that great at it so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You need two regular expressions. One which gets your first 3 lines, the other gets the rest.

```
((?!((inv)|(qty))).*=.*),
```

Will return the values that don't start with inv or qty, and will exclude the comma.

```
(((inv)|(qty)).*=.*),
```

Will likewise get you the cases where it does start with inv or qty, also excluding the comma.

Use `Regex.Matches` to get all the lines that match your regex. You might have to use `RegexOptions.Multiline` I can't test it out right now.

You'll be using group 1, not the full match. Group 1 is the result from the very outermost brackets of these expressions. The full match would save the commas and then we'd have to worry about trimming the last one off.

You now have two collections of strings, use `string.Join` with `','` to bring them together and correctly place commas between lines.